# Module exclusion Firestore implementation android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using realtime Firebase for my app for some time .I need to add Firestore to my project . when adding firestore , I have a duplication error . I would like to exclude modules from firestore and not from other libs .
I can not identify which module should be removed besides gson that was also duplicated.

implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.2'){
exclude module: 'gson',
exclude module:????
}
It seems very close or a duplicate of some other questions but none of the given answsers in previous questions worked

I can not give all gradle because file is very large but main google elements are :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'gson'
    exclude module: 'com.google.gauva:gauva-jdk5:17.0'
}


implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient' exclude module: 'com.google.gauva:gauva-jdk5:17.0'
```

I supppose issue comes from
implementation files('libs\deeparteffects-android-client-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar') but i can not really test it

```
Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.WrappingExecutorService found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.WrappingExecutorService$1 found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.WrappingScheduledExecutorService found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.package-info found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.xml.XmlEscapers found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.common.xml.package-info found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixPatterns found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixType found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
Duplicate class com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.TrieParser found in modules jetified-guava-30.1.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-20.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639529/duplicate-class-com-google-common-util-concurrent-listenablefuture-found-in-modu)

Comment: Thanx, i tried both answers given for this questions and none worked . Weird to have this issue just with firestore and not realtime firebase

Comment: can you share your build.gradle file and check for the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982002/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: Hi, issue seems very similar but just adding elements in the configurations part makes the build fail .I don t which causes duplication issues, i supsect an external modul deepart, but i can not confirm . i can not exclude anything from this module i guess

Comment: is this issue resolved by exclusion ?

Comment: No still not working

Comment: is this answer helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60475474/15774176 ?

Comment: It didn t  help. I don t think this can be related to a specific version of firestore .

Comment: are you able to see anything in logs?

Comment: Logs are displayed in the question

Comment: implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android' have you added it?

Comment: Crashes also by adding guava . As far as i understood, guava is already present in the other implement elements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You  may find this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree/35235229#35235229) helpful to understand the dependency tree.

the syntax you are  using does not match what most documents state : [2](https://tomgregory.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982002) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937743).

**your syntax :**

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'gson'
        exclude module: 'com.google.gauva:gauva-jdk5:17.0'
    }
```

**As mentioned in [blog](https://tomgregory.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/):**

> ```
> configurations.implementation {
>     exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
> }
> ```

**As mentioned in [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982002):**

> ```
> implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0') {
>     exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
>     exclude group:'com.google.guava'
> }
> ```

**As mentioned in [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937743):**

> ```
> configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'protolite-well-known-types')
> ```

Try  changing the configuration syntax to get the desired results

```
configurations.implementation {
  exclude group: 'com.google.gauva', module: 'gauva-jdk5'
}
```

or

```
configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.gauva', module: 'gauva-jdk5')
```

Comment: It was not too clear for me what it really changed but anyway i tried all combinaisons and none worked

Comment: is still the log showing same?

Comment: All the tests give different errors but basically there are duplicate elements issues